# As3 Button Animation rts style

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a simple button that has an animation in it after you click it. Specifically a clockwise circle animates. PacMan dieing is a good example of what i'm trying to do. Think of a pizza pie and every sec a slice gets taken out till its all gone.   Is there a programmatic way of achieving this in ActionScript 3 or do i have to manually animate it in photoshop?

I know how to make a button i'm just not sure how to animate it.  If all else fails i think i'm going to grey out the button and then start a countdown from 9 down to 1 then re-enable it.  I'm still fairly new to As3 advice would be nice. Thankyou

Comment: Are you using the Button type in the Flash Prof.?

Comment: If you are, you should absolutely not use the button type. Everything should be a movieclip or sprite. Use event listeners + buttonMode to emulate buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You take the full circle and put a mask onto it, on which you [draw an according wedge programmatically](http://code.google.com/p/leebrimelow/source/browse/trunk/as3/com/theflashblog/drawing/Wedge.as?r=17).